# virtualbox start/stop on a predetermined time

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is there an easy way to set the virtual machine so that it starts  at about 8:00 am and stops it at 9:00 pm? My host system runs a version of Windows XP 24/07 on which also runs an Apache Webhost, but this is not necessary for the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) command-line utility.

Create commands to start and stop your VM and then use Task Scheduler (look in Control Panel) to add the two tasks at the time you needed.

`VBoxManage startvm <vm>`

`VBoxManage controlvm <vm> savestate`

where `<vm>` is machine name or UUID.